# Replace comma(,) with dot(.) only at particular location in the string

Tags: excel, vba

I have string each on multiple line which looks like this

```
S087A1097,99,86,0,14,0,good
S087A1097,100,0,10,14,0,good
S087A1097,0,0,100,0,0,good
```

And I need to change it to this respectively.

```
S087A1097,99.86,0.14,0,good
S087A1097,100.0,10.14,0,good
S087A1097,0.0,100.0,0,good
```

How can I achieve this in Excel

Comment: If you want to use a VBA based solution, you can read my answer and code below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your text is in cell A1:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,",",".",2),",",".",3)
```

Comment: very fast, nice :)

Comment: Thanks!  And I had to convert my locale ; to , which was a the most confusing part on this one... the whole thing is just commas, dots and quotation marks :)
Yours is very impressive!

Comment: Thanks, mine is longer, but if you don't want to keep formulas in a worksheet, it's a fast solution

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a VBA solution, you can try the code below.

It might seem a little long, but it's very fast to execute since there is little "messing" with the worksheet, and most of the logic is done on Arrays.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub ImportCsvContents()

Dim csvLines As Variant, CurrentRow As Variant
Dim LastRow As Long, i As Long

ReDim csvLines(0)

With Worksheets(1)
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    ' === logic, each order ends with data data in column "B" ===
    For i = 1 To LastRow
        csvLines(UBound(csvLines)) = .Range("A" & i).Value
        ReDim Preserve csvLines(UBound(csvLines) + 1) ' keep record and raise array index by 1
    Next i
End With

' resize array to actual populated size
If csvLines(UBound(csvLines)) = "" Then
    ReDim Preserve csvLines((UBound(csvLines) - 1))
End If


' loop through all lines in .csv file
For i = 0 To UBound(csvLines)
    CurrentRow = Split(csvLines(i), ",")

    CurrentRow(1) = CurrentRow(1) & "." & CurrentRow(2)
    CurrentRow(2) = CurrentRow(3) & "." & CurrentRow(4)
    CurrentRow(3) = CurrentRow(5)
    CurrentRow(4) = CurrentRow(6)

    ' re-format the current line
    csvLines(i) = CurrentRow(0) & "," & CurrentRow(1) & "," & CurrentRow(2) & "," & CurrentRow(3) & "," & CurrentRow(4)

    Erase CurrentRow ' clear array
Next i

' now just dump the entre array to the worksheet
Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Resize(UBound(csvLines) + 1).Value = Application.Transpose(csvLines)

End Sub
```